# How do I plot data in a text file depending on the the value present in one of the columns

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I have a text file with with a header and a few columns, which represents results of experiments where some parameters were fixed to obtain some metrics. the file is he following format :

```
     A    B     C     D     E
0  0.5  0.2  0.25  0.75  1.25
1  0.5  0.3  0.12  0.41  1.40
2  0.5  0.4  0.85  0.15  1.55
3  1.0  0.2  0.11  0.15  1.25
4  1.0  0.3  0.10  0.11  1.40
5  1.0  0.4  0.87  0.14  1.25
6  2.0  0.2  0.23  0.45  1.55
7  2.0  0.3  0.74  0.85  1.25
8  2.0  0.4  0.55  0.55  1.40
```

So I want to plot x = B, y = C for each fixed value of And E so basically for an E=1.25 I want a series of line plots of x = B, y = C at each value of A then a plot for each unique value of E.

Anyone could help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a combination of `groupby()` and `seaborn.lineplot()`:

```
for e,d in df.groupby('E'):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    sns.lineplot(data=d, x='B', y='C', hue='A', ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(e)
```